# ios Extension size

Tags: ios, widget

How to change ios extension height in compact mode?

when I call this function

```
[self.extensionContext setWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode:NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded];
```

widget shows show more/show less button and user able to expand widget but I would like to hide that button somehow and display in large size.